# CSS menu buttons having a random light-blue border at the tom on click or hover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://driptone.com/jony/applications/test/#

Please start clicking on the buttons, and you will notice a light-blue or so border appearing at the bottom of each button.

This will happen without clicking if you hover the last-child (last menu item with the icon).
I am using bootstrap framework.

Why is this happening? Very strange.

This is my HTML code:

```
<header class="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="menuitems">
            <li id="menu-active"><a href="#" >HOMEPAGE</a></li></a>
            <li><a href="#">PLAY NOW</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HUNGER WIKI</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HIGHSCORES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
            <li><div id="login"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
#menu { 
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-header.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menuitems {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;
}

#menuitems li {
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-header.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 56px;
    float: left;
    border-right: solid 1px #44acbf;
    border-left: solid 1px #114a56;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;      
}

#menuitems li:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-1.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;  
    border-right: solid 1px #2b6e81;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;  
}

#menuitems li:last-child:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-menu-login-hover.png") !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#menuitems li:active {
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-onClick-menu.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;  
}

#menuitems li:last-child {
    width: 88px;
    border-right: solid 0px transparent;
}

#menu-active {
    background-image: url("../img/gradient-1.png") !important;
    background-repeat: repeat !important;   
    border-right: solid 1px #2b6e81 !important;
}

#menuitems li:first-child {
    border-left: solid 0px transparent;
}

#login {
    background-image: url("../img/icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 32%;   
    margin-top: 20%;    
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
}

#menuitems a {
    width: 140px;
    height: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent;
    border-top: solid 0px transparent;
}

#menuitems a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent;
    border-top: solid 0px transparent;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think this is due to your gradient image being animated into position over the blue gradient that comes by default.

Comment: set vertical-align to top or bottom to <a> to avoid the gap under them when they sit on baseline :)

Comment: @GCyrillus It is still happening

Comment: @JonyKale This is your second question today to do with that navigation. May I suggest you visit this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-dom-web-design to discuss localized questions. Im there so I am willing to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `transition-timing-function` from `ease` to `linear`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kw4pY/